# TypeError: functionname() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, arguments

I'm trying to pass a dictionary that was initialized in one class as an argument into a method in another class. I wrote this code but no matter how I try to fix it I can't get going to test my other code..

I was trying to pass myDict as an argument in functionname by having class B inherit class A (I'm going to have other classes that will inherit class A and will have a function that takes myDict as an argument as well).

I have this:

```
    class A(object):
         def __init__(self):



    class B(A):
         .....
         def functionname(self, myDict):
               .....


    def otherfunction(text):
         text = function(otherargument) #this function returns a list and for each item in the list I call functionname.
         myDict = {}
         for x in text:
             x.functionname(myDict)
```

I thought this would work but when I try to test my other code I get: TypeError: functionname() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). Am I not approaching this the right way?
This is homework so I would really appreciate some guidance on understanding the concept of this.
Edit: I called functionname from another function outside of the classes. 
The error also starts at the function call (x.functionname()) and says TypeError

Edit: So I tried moving the dictionary that I declared in **init** to otherfunction and it worked and gave me different errors for other parts of code that needs to be fixed. But for this error, it was solved.

Comment: Show us a [minimal runnable example that demonstrates the error when run](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, show us the function call.

Comment: You defined `functionname(self, myDict)` therefore it is epecting 2 parameters. You called this method on object `x` without passing another parameter. This means that only x is passes as parameter corresponding to `self`. You should call it something like `x.functionanme(myDictParam)`.

Comment: Yes, instead of declaring the variable in __init__, I declared it in otherfunction and used x.functionname(myDict) and it solved that error.